# R Filter and subset a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Please give me some advice on the followings.

There is a data frame with three columns, the first one is a datetime(precise to seconds), the second one is a person's name, and the third one is a message.

I want to retrieve the following information and plot them.

1. Messages per person during a certain minute.
2. A certain person's messages during a certain minute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a reproducible example of your dataset will really help with getting a useful response

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of different date formats in R.  If you haven't got a preference for one of them, then use the `lubridate` package.

```
library(lubridate)
```

Some sample data:

```
the_present <- now()
dfr <- data.frame(
  person  = rep(c("Richie", "user900168"), each = 3),
  time    = seq(the_present, by = "-1 min", length.out = 6),
  message = letters[1:6]
)
```

Pick an interesting minute:

```
start_time <- floor_date(the_present, unit = "min")
end_time <- ceiling_date(the_present, unit = "min")
```

Use `subset` and `table` to solve your problems.

```
table(subset(dfr, time > start_time & time <= end_time, person))
subset(dfr, person == "Richie" & time > start_time & time <= end_time)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry for that the question is not clear enough.